# App stops working due to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app was working fine till last week. I haven't changed anything in the source code but suddenly my app keeps crashing whenever the login, register or forgot password links, all of which are connected to Firebase.
Also, can someone please tell me how to attach the log properly? I'm unable to format it.
Thanks in advance!

My log:

```
05-04 11:52:59.592 25672-25697/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connecting to remote service
05-04 11:52:59.599 25672-25697/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
05-04 11:52:59.599 25672-25697/com.securitytechno2018 E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
05-04 11:52:59.599 25672-25697/com.securitytechno2018 E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
05-04 11:52:59.599 25672-25697/com.securitytechno2018 E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
05-04 11:52:59.600 25672-25697/com.securitytechno2018 E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
05-04 11:52:59.603 25672-25672/com.securitytechno2018 W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
05-04 11:52:59.605 25672-25697/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 0
05-04 11:53:30.178 23026-26580/? D/FA-SVC: No app data available; dropping event: com.securitytechno2018
05-04 11:53:45.533 23912-26810/? W/CronetSyncConnectionRcs: Upload content type not set.
05-04 11:53:46.014 2936-26865/? I/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/phenotype.db has been closed but there are still 1 connections in use.  They will be closed as they are released back to the pool.
05-04 11:56:09.340 2936-2950/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/phenotype.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50153859/6925888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the firebase version & Google Play Service version in your dependency. First update google play services; If it works ignore the firebase version.

[Here's an answer to similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120919/service-version-update-required-error-using-firebase-analytics-on-android)

Comment: Thank you! Updating google play services worked for me :)